# How to interpolate an index on html Vue list templates?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs2

please take a look at the following code. It's written right in an html page, so no standalone components here. It's for a Vue js app.

```
  <div v-for="(screw, index) in form.screws " class="screw-module">
    <input type="radio" name="screws[index][prop1]" v-model="screws[index].prop1" id="prop1" value="prop1">
    <input type="radio" name="screws[index][prop2]" v-model="screws[index].prop2" id="prop2" value="prop2">
    <input type="radio" name="screws[index][prop3]" v-model="screws[index].prop3" id="prop2" value="prop3">
  </div>
```

Now please focus on `name="screws[index][thread]"`. What I need as the rendered html name value, is:

```
// iteration 1
name="screws[0][prop1]"
name="screws[0][prop2]"

// iteration 2
name="screws[1][prop1]"
name="screws[1][prop2]"
```

And so on.. What's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You can use string interpolation for this

```
<input type="radio" :name="`screws[${index}][prop3]`">
```

Comment: also, you don't need `index` since you can use `screw`, so `<input type="radio" :name="screw[prop3]">`

Comment: Mmm I don't think so. I just updated my question. The name value must result in a string to be used by php interpreter. So the only variable I need to be resolved is index. The rest of the name should be just plain string. Therefore, iteration one will be rendered as screws[0][prop1], iteration2 as screws[1][prop1], and so on. In other words, the only thing should change in resulting html is the index value.

Comment: This works. Strange enough, this exact syntax seems not to be documented in official docs on the templates sections.. Anyone knows of some (un)offical docs or articles about?

Comment: @LucaReghellin This is not actually part of Vue templating, but string interpolation or template literals introduced in newer Javascript specification. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It is used in conjunction with Vue template binding (`v-bind:` or simply `:`).

Comment: You can see template literals support for browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals). If any browser you want does not support it, you can use old school string concatenation like this. `:name="'screws[' + index + '][prop3]'"`